# Rails app and api in same application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have been writing a Rails version api that works under a subdomain. I have configured all the controllers to `respond_to :json` by default. This was done because initially the app just had to be an api and no web facing end point was required.

The client has now asked for a web application as well. I want to keep the structure of my api under a subdomain/versioned. What is the best strategy to build the web facing app on top of this api in the same application. Naturally I want to keep it DRY and performance is a concern too. Is the best way to change existing code so that it can respond to both html and json requests?

Routes.rb is something like this:

```
  namespace :api, path: '/',constraints: { :subdomain =>  'api' },:defaults => {:format => :json} do 
    namespace :v1 do
     with_options only: :index do |list_only|

         list_only.resources :users
      end

      match "home/:action" => "home#:action"
      match "explore/:action" => "explore#:action"
      match "users/:action" => "users#:action"
      match "comment/:action"  => "comment#:action"
      match "question/:action" => "question#:action"
      match "apimain/:action"  => "apimain#:action"
      match "search/:action"  => "search#:action"
      resources :questions, only: :create
    end
  end
```

And controllers like this:

```
module API
  module V1

            class ApimainController < ActionController::Base
               respond_to :json
               def ping
                   result = 1 
                   respond_with result.to_json
               end
   end
end
```

Comment: consider building the 'web application' as a Single Page Application (SPA) using Ember.js or Angular instead of using rails html.erb view templates. The SPA would just talk to your existing API via json.